# Button autocaps text with api version 21 or higher in Android. Why?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, textview

I am trying to set text to a button like `Go To Url` and as result on screen i'm getting `GO TO URL` while compiling with Android API 21 , I don't want to show all text in CAPS, what i am missing ? Please help.

[image]

Comment: For you 1st question - It's not a bug. It's a default property. Didn't quite understood your 2nd question.

Comment: Are you tried adding your values in string.xml.

Comment: set allCaps property of button to false in xml

Comment: ok thanks for your reply @ArnabJain my 2 question is the only issue i'm facing i don't want to show text of button in CAPS , i want to show text as defined in xml like in my case "Go To Url"  .

Comment: As stated in the comment above yours try setting allCaps to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Need to set auto CAPS property of a button as false in xml

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to know how you should assign the text of your button?
The best practice would be to assign a [String Ressource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) in your XML file to the buttons android:text attribute.
This way you have all your strings in one place and can easily localize your app in different languages.

This is how your button should look like:

Your layout file:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/go_to_url_label"
    android:textAllCaps="false">
```

Your strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
   ...
   <string name="go_to_url_label">Go to URL</string>
   ...
</resources>
```